# sidebar on image attachment page

Tags: wordpress

When you post a gallery inside a post and link to the attachment page (ie: [gallery columns="4"] )so each image gets it's own page. The sidebar doesn't show up on those pages for some reason.

Would it be possible to fix?

I am using twentyeleven theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit your image.php template and make sure it's calling `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`